# Software Center crashing already tried uninstalling and re-installing

Tags: software-center

Software Center crashes.  I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.  Already have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Software Center.  Here's the error I get:

```
user@pc:~$ software-center
2014-12-21 15:34:40,540 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2014-12-21 15:34:40,553 - softwarecenter.db.database - INFO - open() database: path=None use_axi=True use_agent=True
2014-12-21 15:34:41,677 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2014-12-21 15:34:42,114 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - show_available_packages: search_text is '', app is None.
2014-12-21 15:34:42,290 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 243, in open
    self._cache = apt.Cache(GtkMainIterationProgress())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 105, in __init__
    self.open(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 154, in open
    self._list.read_main_list()
SystemError: E:Opening /etc/apt/sources.list - ifstream::ifstream (13: Permission denied)
2014-12-21 15:34:47,498 - softwarecenter.db.enquire - ERROR - _get_estimate_nr_apps_and_nr_pkgs failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 115, in _get_estimate_nr_apps_and_nr_pkgs
    tmp_matches = enquire.get_mset(0, len(self.db), None, xfilter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/appfilter.py", line 89, in __call__
    if (not pkgname in self.cache and
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 263, in __contains__
    return self._cache.__contains__(k)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__contains__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 176, in <module>
    app.run(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1422, in run
    self.show_available_packages(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1352, in show_available_packages
    self.view_manager.set_active_view(ViewPages.AVAILABLE)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/session/viewmanager.py", line 154, in set_active_view
    view_widget.init_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/availablepane.py", line 171, in init_view
    self.apps_filter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/catview_gtk.py", line 238, in __init__
    self.build(desktopdir)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/catview_gtk.py", line 511, in build
    self._build_homepage_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/catview_gtk.py", line 271, in _build_homepage_view
    self._append_whats_new()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/catview_gtk.py", line 450, in _append_whats_new
    whats_new_cat = self._update_whats_new_content()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/catview_gtk.py", line 439, in _update_whats_new_content
    docs = whats_new_cat.get_documents(self.db)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/categories.py", line 124, in get_documents
    nonblocking_load=False)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 317, in set_query
    self._blocking_perform_search()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 212, in _blocking_perform_search
    matches = enquire.get_mset(0, self.limit, None, xfilter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/appfilter.py", line 89, in __call__
    if (not pkgname in self.cache and
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 263, in __contains__
    return self._cache.__contains__(k)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__contains__'
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to say "`sudo`?" (but I think Software Center can sudo itself...)

But what's with this error

```
 SystemError: E:Opening /etc/apt/sources.list - ifstream::ifstream (13: Permission denied)
```

Is your /etc/apt/sources.list not readable or something? Did you do something to change your software sources? That might be the problem, unless Software Center is exiting for some other reason. Not really a "crash" is it, anything in `dmesg` or `/var/log/syslog/`?

Comment: I added the spotify repository to sources.list.  "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free", but that souldn't really affect it should it?

Comment: Possibly, if the sources.list file isn't readable anymore. FYI, Mine's permissions are this: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   118 Jun 17 11:02 sources.list` you could change yours with `chmod`, or `sudo chmod`, maybe a `chmod a+r` would make it readable enough to work, *if* that's the problem (I don't know the "numeric code" to match `-rw-r--r--`, never liked them)

Answer (score 1):

The errors seem to be caused due to errors in the `software-center` cache.

Delete the cache and try again. To do this, navigate to the cache folder -

`cd ~/.cache`

Remove the software center cache folder -

`rm -r software-center`

Comment: Tried this.  Didn't work unfortunately.